# Summarize and improving ArrayAdapter with FOR looping

Tags: java, android, arrays, for-loop, android-arrayadapter

I want to Summarize my code with looping

For example if I have a code like this:

```
spinnerDinamik.addView(txtKolom[0]);
spinnerDinamik.addView(spnKolom[0]);
spinnerDinamik.addView(txtKolom[1]);
spinnerDinamik.addView(spnKolom[1]);
spinnerDinamik.addView(txtKolom[2]);
spinnerDinamik.addView(spnKolom[2]);
```

I can make it simple like this:

```
for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
  spinnerDinamik.addView(txtKolom[itung]);
  spinnerDinamik.addView(spnKolom[itung]);
}
```

But on my problem, I want to use this looping into my array adapter.

First, I declare my array adapter like this:

```
ArrayAdapter<String>[] dataAdapterKolom;
dataAdapterKolom = new ArrayAdapter[labelKolom.size()];
```

and I make a code like this:

```
final List<String> labelJenis = db.getJenis();
final List<String> labelTipe = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> labelKode = new ArrayList<String>();

dataAdapterKolom[0] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelJenis);
dataAdapterKolom[1] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelTipe);
dataAdapterKolom[2] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelKode);

for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
 dataAdapterKolom[itung].setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
 spnKolom[itung].setAdapter(dataAdapterKolom[itung]);
}
```

**My Expectation**

in this code:

```
final List<String> labelJenis = db.getJenis();
final List<String> labelTipe = new ArrayList<String>();
final List<String> labelKode = new ArrayList<String>();
```

I want to make `final List<String>` into array, and use `for` looping.

and then I can change this code:

```
dataAdapterKolom[0] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelJenis);
dataAdapterKolom[1] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelTipe);
dataAdapterKolom[2] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelKode);
```

into this code:

```
for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
  dataAdapterKolom[itung] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelKolom[itung]);
}
```

**This is my full code**

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity{

    TextView[] txtKolom;
    Spinner[] spnKolom;
    ArrayAdapter<String>[] dataAdapterKolom;
    ViewGroup spinnerDinamik;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        spinnerDinamik = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.bikinLayout);

        final DataHelper db = new DataHelper(getApplicationContext());
        final List<String> labelKolom = db.getKolom();

        txtKolom = new TextView[labelKolom.size()];
        spnKolom = new Spinner[labelKolom.size()];
        dataAdapterKolom = new ArrayAdapter[labelKolom.size()];

        for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
            txtKolom[itung] = new TextView(this);
            txtKolom[itung].setText(labelKolom.get(itung).toString());
            spnKolom[itung] = new Spinner(this);
            spinnerDinamik.addView(txtKolom[itung]);
            spinnerDinamik.addView(spnKolom[itung]);
        }

        final List<String> labelJenis = db.getJenis();
        final List<String> labelTipe = new ArrayList<String>();
        final List<String> labelKode = new ArrayList<String>();

        dataAdapterKolom[0] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelJenis);
        dataAdapterKolom[1] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelTipe);
        dataAdapterKolom[2] = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, labelKode);

        for (int itung=0;itung<labelKolom.size();itung++){
            dataAdapterKolom[itung].setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
            spnKolom[itung].setAdapter(dataAdapterKolom[itung]);
        }

        spnKolom[0].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                labelTipe.clear();
                List<String> labelTipeIsi = db.getTipe(labelJenis.get(i).toString());

                for (String loop : labelTipeIsi) {
                    labelTipe.add(loop);
                }

                dataAdapterKolom[1].notifyDataSetChanged();
                dataAdapterKolom[2].notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
        spnKolom[1].setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                labelKode.clear();
                List<String> labelKodeIsi = db.getKode(spnKolom[0].getSelectedItem().toString(), labelTipe.get(i).toString());
                for (String looop : labelKodeIsi) {
                    labelKode.add(looop);
                }
                dataAdapterKolom[2].notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I have 3 spinner on my program. I use `dataAdapterKolom` to set Adapter on my spinner.

Comment: please provide the full adapter code, since variable are not in english and since the code is really splitted, is hard to understand the problem.

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley I will update it